# Ubuntu 12.4.2 Server, after installation black screen with _ on the left top (3 times the same) (no GRUB)

Tags: installation, server

hi i have problem with ubuntu server 12.4.2 64bit on IBM server 366 series 4x Xenon 64bit 16GB ram, after installation first time with grub in bootloader screen i cant change anything and after 15 minutes run black screan, nest installation there is the same black screen but load system i have installed ubuntu graphic terminal and ssh and after few minutes system stop and after restart black screen and nothing for 1h, third installation after all instalation proces i chose to not install grub and after all process i see only black screen with left top screan ticking _, any suggestions ?, i tried to install 32 bit system and working fine but cant install 64bit java on it and thats why i need 64bit system, and yes all 4 processors are 64bit Xenon 3,16 Ghz 800mhz fsb ht, 2x Hdd 73gb 10k hotswap sas server raid 8i, 16GB ram, integrated graphic card. Any suggestions ? ... HELP !

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a different Distro/Version, just to see what happens...

I've seen this behaviour on an Asus PC recently, and I just couldn't install Linux at all, you're more lucky than me as you can install the 32 bit version, so I think you should try a different distro (debian?) or ubuntu version (like 11.04, 12.10, etc)

Comment: ill try older ubuntu version beceose i have problems with debian bootable cd, any one know what vesion i can install on Intel Xenon 64 bit beceose ia64 whean i put dvd in i have errors that cant see dvd with debian

Answer (score 0):

Hello Black screen with the dash only symbol; Guess what? you're not the only one; I've got the same thing trying to replace windows seven on an HP pavillion; at first it appeared as if it had completed a successful download but then when trying to execute, I got nothing also but the dash in the corner.  Try booting an earlier version without going online to download it.  This means you will have to find someone you know and trust to give a free copy of say 10.04 version which I remember to be a fantastic version with no hiccups like this one.   Then use the update features to get up to date.

Comment: ill try what you say, older version of ubuntu, maybe you have answear why debian ia64 wont install (dont see cd) whean i want to boot ? i tried do download on 3 computers this version but doesnt want to boot